# Java Swing : managing the "MousePressed" event on a component until it is released

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls

here I try, in my custom panel, to repulse a ball while a user click on a custom ventilator component (it is just a blue square, the component is inherited from JButton).

**But the problem is that the event is only managed when the user click the ventilator, and not all the time the mouse is down on the ventilator.**

Here my different classes. Thank in advance

***PhysicsPanel.java***

```
package com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels;

import com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.gui.MainFrame;

public class PhysicsPanels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

***MainFrame.java***

```
package com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.gui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.gui.the_panels.VentilatorPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame(){
        setIntrinsicsProperties();
        addPanels();
    }

    private void setIntrinsicsProperties() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        setTitle("Physics panels application");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void addPanels() {
        JTabbedPane mainContainer = new JTabbedPane();
        add(mainContainer);
        mainContainer.addTab("Ventilator", new VentilatorPanel());
        /*
         * This tab is not usefull for the question =>
         * mainContainer.addTab("Rotating plate", new RotatingPlatePanel());
         */
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

***VentilatorPanel.java***

```
package com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.gui.the_panels;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.custom_components.BallComponent;
import com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.custom_components.VentilatorComponent;

public class VentilatorPanel extends JPanel {

    public VentilatorPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);

        ventilatorObject.setSimpleTaskOnMousedPressed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                repulseBall();
            }

        });
        add(ventilatorObject);
        add(ballObject);
        ventilatorObject.setLocation(100, 80);
        ballObject.setLocation(160, 90);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    private void repulseBall(){
        Point oldBallLocation = ballObject.getLocation();
        ballObject.setLocation(oldBallLocation.x + 5, oldBallLocation.y);
        repaint();
    }

    private VentilatorComponent ventilatorObject = new VentilatorComponent(60,60);
    private BallComponent ballObject = new BallComponent(40);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

***VentilatorComponent.java***

```
package com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.custom_components;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class VentilatorComponent extends JButton {

    public VentilatorComponent(Dimension size){
        super();
        enableInputMethods(true);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                    doReactToClick();
                }
        });
        setSize(size);
    }

    public VentilatorComponent(int width, int height){
        this(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    /**
     * Sets the task that will be executed on mouse pressing.
     * Be carefull !!! Must be a very simple task (no looping inside)
     * @param r - Runnable
     */
    public void setSimpleTaskOnMousePressed(Runnable task){
        taskOnClick = task;
    }

    protected void doReactToClick() {
        new Thread(taskOnClick).run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private Runnable taskOnClick;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

***BallComponent.java***

```
package com.gmail.loloof64.java_swing.physics_panels.custom_components;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class BallComponent extends JComponent {

    public BallComponent(int diameter){
        setSize(new Dimension(diameter, diameter));
    }   

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics.fillOval(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Comment: Yes, it because I started my project planning to add other tabbed panes on the one hand, and here I favor reusing and I make management more easy by creating components instead of just managing all in the panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without reading all of your code, the problem might be as follows: `Mousepressed` is triggered only once, when the user presses down the button. You have to save that state in a variable (e.g. `boolean pressed = true`), and then react also to `mousereleased` events, which set your variable to false. By the state of your variable you know then whether the mouse button is currently pressed or released.

Comment: Oh you're right, but I thought there was a way to manage it without saving the state. Impossible ? So, I'll go to work with your advice. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, with the current class design, I don't manage to avoid to block the UI Thread while trying to implement the mouse "pressing" functionnality.

Comment: Instead of the boolean variable, you can start a new thread which does the `repulseBall` thing on `mousepressed` and kill the thread on `mousereleased`

Comment: Finally I managed :) I creating a new Thread subclass, which takes the wanted Runnable as an argument, and inside, I wrote my own finish() method. The run() method of this new class creates and launch new threads of the runnable while this subclass is not required to be finished. Finally, the runnable must have a simple run() ... without any loop (neither while, neither for, neither do). So it is a kind of Thread decorator :)

Answer (score 1):

To get events that are generated when the mouse is in a pressed state you need to use a MouseMotionListener and handle the mouseDragged() event.

Comment: But do you get those events also if the mouse is not moved?

Comment: I tried with MouseDragged event, but i works only if I also move into the ventilator while pressing the button :S